# How to add a filed with tag options to selection in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add a field for the tag selection. If I select a tag the tag should show in the textfiled and the selected item should be removed from the tag list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

U have to do it manually. Check this, code [here](https://github.com/jbjason/trend_practice/blob/main/lib/screens/youtube_chip/youtube_chip_screen.dart). Demo [duration 1.59s to end](https://www.loom.com/share/f519b6db3eec48ed90bb6804c7c007fe)

Comment: this is not I want